# Query Custom Post Types with checkboxes

Tags: custom-post-types, query, array

I have Custom Post Type (Courses) with a field "course-location" that is a checkbox.
I would like to filter the listing page with the checked items.

The below code is working when I select ONE checkbox, however, it is not working with multiple-checked items.

How can I have

> OR statement

working to return many courses?

**CODE**

```
$searchArray = array();
$searchArray[] = array('relation' => 'OR',);

// loop over checked checkboxes
if(!empty($_POST['course_location'])) {
    foreach($_POST['course_location'] as $check) {
        // echo '<h1>'.$check.'</h1>'; 
        $searchArray[] = array('key' => 'course_location','value' => $check,'compare' => 'LIKE',);
    }
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'course' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'meta_query' => $searchArray
    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

**FORM**

```
<form name="courseSearch" id="courseSearch" method="post">
los-angeles-county: <input type="checkbox" name="course_location[]" value="los-angeles-county" /><br/>
orange-county: <input type="checkbox" name="course_location[]" value="orange-county" /><br/>
test: <input type="checkbox" name="course_location[]" value="test" /><br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You can't query by "checkboxes" - can you clarify if these attributes are taxonomy terms or post meta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't constructing the `meta_query` correctly. It is close but not quite right.

```
$searchArray = array();
$searchArray = array('relation' => 'OR',); // here is the change

// loop over checked checkboxes
if(!empty($_POST['course_location'])) {
    foreach($_POST['course_location'] as $check) {
        // echo '<h1>'.$check.'</h1>'; 
        $searchArray[] = array('key' => 'course_location','value' => $check,'compare' => 'LIKE',);
    }
}
```

As you have it written you were getting:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["relation"]=>
    string(2) "OR"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(15) "course_location"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(15) "course_location"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
}
```

And you need:

```
array(3) {
  ["relation"]=>
    string(2) "OR"
  [0=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(15) "course_location"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["key"]=>
    string(15) "course_location"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["compare"]=>
    string(4) "LIKE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - changing the initial array setup worked. I used **echo '<pre>'; print_r($searchArray); echo '</pre>';** to dump the array to screen.